# Error TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run notebook new_project I got an error:

> self.notes.append(participant(job, pname, pstages, participant))
>       TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Anybody know why? And is my `new_project` code correct? Or will there be another error? Help please I'm still studying about Python and now I'm trying to apply inheritance in my code

Here is the code

```
import datetime


last_id = 0


class project:

    def __init__(self, job, pname, pstages):
        self.pname = pname
        self.pstages = pstages
        self.job = job
        global last_id
        last_id += 1
        self.id = last_id

        self.list_of_project=[]


    def match(self, filter):

        return filter in self.pname

class participant(project):

    def __init__(self, job, pname, pstages, participant, pid):
        super(participant,self).__init__(job, pname, pstages)
        self.participant = participant  
        self.pid = project.id
        self.list_of_participants=[]

class notebook:

    def __init__(self):
        self.notes = []

    def new_project(self, job, pname, pstages, participant):
        self.notes.append(participant(job, pname, pstages, participant))

    def new_pstages(self, pstages, pname=''):
        self.notes.append(project(pstages, pname))

    def _find_project(self, project_id):
        for project in self.notes:
            if str(project.id) == str(project_id):
                return project

        return None

    def modify_pstages(self, project_id, pstages):
        project = self._find_project(project_id)
        if project:
            project.pstages = pstages
            return True
        return False

    def search(self, filter):
        return [project for project in self.notes if
                project.match(filter)]
```

Comment: Because, there is also a variable in the name `participant`.

Comment: thanks for the help !, no problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
def new_project(self, job, pname, pstages, participant):
    self.notes.append(participant(job, pname, pstages, participant))
```

Your function has an argument named `participant`, so it's trying to call that as a function. You can either rename the function argument like so:

```
def new_project(self, job, pname, pstages, part): # <- choose any name you want
    self.notes.append(participant(job, pname, pstages, part))
```

or you could rename the `participant` class. By convention, class names are typically capitalized:

```
def new_project(self, job, pname, pstages, participant):
    self.notes.append(Participant(job, pname, pstages, participant))
```

Note that if you rename the class, you have to change its name everywhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The participant in the new_project parameters is overriding the class named participant:

```
class participant(project):

[..]


    def new_project(self, job, pname, pstages,  --> participant <--):
        self.notes.append( --> participant <-- (job, pname, pstages, participant))
```

You end up trying to call a string with the parameters `job, pname, pstages, participant`